# 'Boot Device Not Found' after installing an SSD with Ubuntu on my laptop

Tags: boot, secure-boot

UPDATE: FIXED AND SOLVED

All it really took was switching the Legacy Mode on and the OS booted up just fine. Cheers!

So the HDD on my laptop died and I was told to replace it. I brought my old SSD, which I previously used on my gaming rig, with an already set-up Ubuntu on it to the repair shop. They installed the drive itself into the laptop but could not finish the job due to not having a Linux expert on their team.

When I turn on the laptop the system cannot boot the OS and the 'Boot Device Not Found' error shows up.

The drive has passed the disc check successfully and has been recognized so far. I have a USB-stick with a Ubuntu Live on it and when I loaded it up I could clearly see my SSD with all the Linux files in it.

I turnt the Secure Boot option on but I cannot change or find the keys. I remember I had to do something with it when I first installed Ubuntu 3 or 4 years ago.

Anyway, how do I fix this issue? Has anyone else faced this exact same problem?

Comment: Probably the bootloader is not properly installed on the new disk. Easiest way would be to just install a fresh Ubuntu on the new disk and copy what you need from the old. Otherwise you could try to boot into a live system on a USB drive and try to fix the bootloader from there, but that's more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm not sure how the bootloader could be the issue here because I clearly remember that it was working just fine years ago. I have a Ubuntu Live USB though.

Comment: No, what I mean is that in order for a disk to boot the OS, the bootloader has to be installed in the MBR of the disk. If you say the guys replacing your disk don't know Linux, they probably just copied the files over to the new disk and called it a day, which is not gonna do it. You can find some pointers [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal) if you want to attempt to fix it.

Comment: No, the SSD already had Ubuntu installed on it from way before. They just replaced the laptop's HDD with my SSD, they did not touch the files. No copy-paste was involved.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it somehow. All it took was switching the Legacy Mode on and the OS booted up just fine. Thank you, Sebastian!